# do distances in cosmology astropy contain a factor h?

Tags: python, astropy

I am using the astropy cosmology package and was wondering if the unit returned using the methods, for example, comoving_distance or kpc_comoving_per_arcmin are returned in h^-1 Mpc and h^-1 kpc or just straight Mpc and kpc?

Answer (score 2):

In straight Mpc and kpc.

You can verify this by trying cosmologies with everything else the same but a different value for h, and you will see that the distances change.

```
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.cosmology import LambdaCDM
LambdaCDM(50 * u.km / u.s / u.Mpc, 0.3).comoving_distance(3)
LambdaCDM(100 * u.km / u.s / u.Mpc, 0.3).comoving_distance(3)
```

The first returns about 9000 Mpc, the second 4500; if they were in h^-1 Mpc they would be the same (well, almost -- there are some very small effects from things like Omega_photon that depend on h).